Azure Services Connectivity Watchdog
I'm developing a system with a microservices architecture that relies on several Azure services for continuous inter-service communication. For context, here's a simplified overview of my setup:

Container App: Hosts the Django application.
Keda-Scaled Container Apps: Hosts a data processing engine as a workaround for Azure Functions' limitations.
SQL Database: Supports the Django app.
Blob Storage and Azure Storage Service Queue: Facilitate communication between Django and the data processing engine, enabling KEDA scaling.
Azure Function: Handles minimal-resource requests.

This setup excludes network-related components for simplicity.
I aim to create a mechanism to verify the proper connectivity among all components. Initially, I considered a watchdog script that runs periodically (every 6 or 12 hours) to perform connectivity checks. Here's a simplified version of the script:
class Watchdog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status_file_path = Path("/var/watchdog/status.txt")

    def __call__(self):
        if not self.__is_check_needed():
            logger.info("No need to run watchdog")
            return
        logger.info("Running watchdog connectivity checks.")
        self.__run_checks()
        self.__update_status_file()

    def __is_check_needed(self) -> bool:
        if not self.status_file_path.exists():
            logger.info("Watchdog status file does not exist. ")
            return True
        status_creation_time = (datetime.now() - modification_date(self.status_file_path)).total_seconds()
        logger.info(f"Watchdog status files was created {status_creation_time} seconds ago")
        if status_creation_time > self.check_frequency:
            logger.info(f"Watchdog status is too old {status_creation_time}"
                        "We need to run it again.")
            return True
        return False
     
     def __run_checks(self):
        self.__check_connection_to_sql()
        self.__check_connection_to_blob()
        self.__check_connection_to_queue()
        # remaining checks goes here


This approach works for long-lived Azure Container apps but isn't suitable for short-lived data processing components due to potential system latency impact. Additionally, I'm unsure how to execute dedicated scripts on Keda workers, making this solution inapplicable in some cases.
Questions:

How can I incorporate the mentioned watchdog functionality to be able to monitor the KEDA scaler?
How can I integrate this watchdog functionality with GitHub Actions or Azure DevOps pipelines to enhance deployment processes, especially in terms of communicating execution status between Azure Container App and GitHub Action Worker?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and I'm open to collaborating or sharing this project if there's interest.

I will certainly proceed with this once I've verified the effectiveness of the proposed solution.


This approach works for long-lived Azure Container apps but isn't suitable for short-lived data processing components due to potential system latency impact.


Use sidecar container along with the data processing engine in the same pod. This sidecar will be the responsible for health checks, logging, and reporting status to a centralized monitoring system that which we configure.

When the data processing engine container starts, the sidecar also starts and monitors its lifecycle.


deploy.yml :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: data-processing
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: data-processing
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: deploy
        image: deploy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "curl http://localhost:8081/shutdown"]
      - name: my-app
        image: my-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        command: ["python", "watchdog_script.py"]

my app.yml:
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-appcon
        image: my-app
        command: ["python", "watchdog_script.py"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4

watchdog_script.py:
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Watchdog:
    def __init__(self, check_frequency=43200):
        self.status_file_path = Path("/var/watchdog/status.txt")
        self.check_frequency = check_frequency  

    def __call__(self):
        if not self.__is_check_needed():
            logger.info("No need to run watchdog")
            return
        logger.info("Running watchdog connectivity checks.")
        self.__run_checks()
        self.__update_status_file()

    def __is_check_needed(self) -> bool:
        if not self.status_file_path.exists():
            logger.info("Watchdog status file does not exist.")
            return True
        status_creation_time = (datetime.now() - self.__modification_date(self.status_file_path)).total_seconds()
        logger.info(f"Watchdog status file was created {status_creation_time} seconds ago")
        if status_creation_time > self.check_frequency:
            logger.info(f"Watchdog status is too old ({status_creation_time} seconds). We need to run it again.")
            return True
        return False

    def __run_checks(self):
        self.__check_connection_to_sql()
        self.__check_connection_to_blob()
        self.__check_connection_to_queue()
        self.__check_keda_scaled_components()

    def __check_connection_to_sql(self):
        # SQL check implementation
        pass

    def __check_connection_to_blob(self):
        # Blob Storage check implementation
        pass

    def __check_connection_to_queue(self):
        # Queue check implementation
        pass

    def __check_keda_scaled_components(self):
        # Implement a check for KEDA scaled components
        response = requests.get("http://keda-metrics-endpoint/health")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            logger.info("KEDA scaled components are healthy")
        else:
            logger.error("KEDA scaled components health check failed")

    def __update_status_file(self):
        self.status_file_path.touch()

    @staticmethod
    def __modification_date(file_path):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(file_path.stat().st_mtime)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    watchdog = Watchdog()
    watchdog()

Result:


Instead of running a long-lived service, package the watchdog functionality as a Kubernetes Job. This above approach will check the watchdog runs independently and periodically checks the health of the services, including KEDA-scaled components.


I wasn't aware that adding an additional component to the Azure Container App was an option. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I plan to implement it in my setup and will update you on its success once I've had the chance to do so.
